# PHP: Where should I store the text for info & warning messages

Tags: php, code-separation

I have a question concerning the design of my project's Code.
In most cases, it is important to separate content from code (HTML mixed with PHP in bigger apps=No good idea, etc.) but how should I handle things like the text of error messages?

Assuming this one message will be only used in one case/PHP file:

```
MessageBox( 'Something gone wrong, probably your fault' );
```

or

```
MessageBox( Lang::error_usersfault );
```

(Where `Lang` is a class located in some config file, full of `const`s)

- If you have any experiences (I think every PHP programmer will come across something like this) with things like in the example above - What are they? How do you solve it?
- What is the better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you'll find php extension `gettext` useful?

```
MessageBox(_("Have a nice day"));
```

[PHP Manual of Gettext::gettext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php)